# Circular References and Low Level Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, osdev

I've got a file called `idt.c`, and in this file, I need to call the function `idt_load` from assembly. Now, this would work just fine, except that I need to access a variable, `idtp` from the assembly file, and the variable is declared in idt.c

This won't work, because the linker will tell me that either idt_load is undefined or idtp is undefined. How can I get this to work?

Relevant parts of idt.c

```
struct idt_entry
{
    unsigned short base_lo;
    unsigned short sel;
    unsigned char always0;
    unsigned char flags;
    unsigned short base_hi;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct idt_ptr
{
    unsigned short limit;
    unsigned int base;
} __attribute__((packed));


struct idt_entry idt[256];
struct idt_ptr idtp;

extern void idt_load();

//Later in the code...
idt_load();
```

idt.asm

```
global idt_load
extern idtp
idt_load:
    lidt [idtp]
    ret
```

Comment: Just for fun, why don't you show us the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to think out:

1. `idt` is of what type?  (Ans: it's a pointer to `idt_entry`, or strictly it's the name of the address `idt[0]`.)
2. How would you declare an external reference to a pointer in the asm file?

The easiest way to get all this stuff is to compile the C code with the appropriate flag (at least in gcc I *think* it's -S) and see the generated assembly code.

You don't have any circular reference, you just need to make the linker aware that you want to refer to the memory defined in the C code named `idt`.